# 日本語に違和感: ユーザープロフィールの「閲覧」セクションの各見出し

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

URL例: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

[image: 「閲覧」セクション]

<sub>「表示済み」の項目は自分のプロフィールを見ているときだけ表示されます。</sub>

原文の例:

```
visits  member for  6 years
        visited 1478 days, 26 consecutive
        seen    [1 min ago とか]
```

不自然な点:

- 「閲覧」だと意味合いが伝わらない
- 「次のメンバー」は意味が違う
- 「表示済み」は意味が違う
- 「1日連続」は意味が伝わらない

Comment: この質問がCommunity♦によって更新されているのは、回答が承認されていないから注目させるために、ということでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。回答が承認されていない、かつスコアも0なので[Community♦](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1419/30)の目にとまったようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 「閲覧」→「アクセス」
- 「次のメンバー」→「登録期間」
- 「表示済み」→「アクセス日数」
- 「1日連続」→「現在連続 1 日」

合わせると:

```
アクセス  
    登録期間: 100 日  
    アクセス日数: 100 日（現在連続 26 日）  
    最終ログイン: たった今
```

短い文章は非常に難しい。提案があれば、更新します。

Comment: アクセスと登録期間、いいですね。残りの翻訳案を追加編集しました

Comment: @ento CSSの調整もできるため、デザイナーと確認してみます。モバイル版がネックになるかもけど、とりあえず確認してみます。

Comment: む、CSSの調整って、「アクセス」と「登録期間」の間の改行のことですか? でしたらそれは、改行した方がいいんじゃない、という意味で入れたわけではないです。その方がコピペしやすそうだったので改行しました。

Comment: @ento 「うち最大連続 1 日」より、現在の連続ログインを表しているため、それだけを更新していないです。

Comment: これは失敬、「現在連続 x 日」に修正しました

Comment: 「現在連続」の箇所がそのままですが、 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1498/30 でも案が出ているので、こちらは「済み」にします