# 日本語に違和感：ユーザーページ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

いくつか気づいたものを挙げます。一応メタで検索はかけましたが重複があるかもしれません。

`登録期間:` → `登録から`（コロンも取る）  
`最終ログイン:` → `最後の訪問`（ログイン時間ではない、コロンも取る）  
`プロフィール ビュー   N` → `プロフィールの閲覧   N 回（人？）`  
`X 日、Y 日連続` → `Y 日連続 計 X 日` （あるいは[この方式](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/63/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F-%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE-%E9%96%B2%E8%A6%A7-%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%90%84%E8%A6%8B%E5%87%BA%E3%81%97/81#81)でも）  
`自己紹介` → `情報`  
`自分について` → `自己紹介`（こちらの方が**自己紹介**に近いと思います）  
`サマリー` → `概要` or `略歴`  
`票`（タブ名） → `投票`  
`N 信用度` → `信用度 N` or `N 点の信用度`（**信用度**を単位に使うのは変）  
`クラス`（バッジの欄） → `ランク` or `階級` or `等級`  
`お気に入りの質問がありません` → `お気に入りの質問はありません`  
`N 件の操作`（アクティビティ内） → `N 件の行動`（操作していないものも含まれている）  
`推奨` (suggestion) → `提案`  
（`アクティビティ`（タブ名） → `出来事（？）` ※これはそのままでもいいかもしれません）  
`票   アクティビティ   新着`（並べ替え部分） → `得票順   更新（日時）順   新着順`（[こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F-%E7%A5%A8/1379#1379)を参考に）

Answer (score 1):

８割をTransifex上で適用しました。一部は不可能（例：プロフィールビューN**回** ができない理由は、「N」はストリングに入っていないですので、そのあとの「回」は追加できません）